# How many times a line with equation $y = ax+b \pmod P$ over a prime finite field intersect the edge before "linking" two point

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, finite-fields

If I plot two points
for example:

$Q=(16,56)$ and
$R=(67,11)$
on a plane defined in $x$ and $y$ axes by a finite over a prime finite field $P$ ($79$ for example),
what is the modular equation to find the number of times that a line with an equation

$$y=ax+b \pmod  P$$

cuts the $y$ edge (where $y=P$) of the plane if I start from $Q$ to reach $R$ knowing that $Q$ and $R$ are collinear on the line?

Answer (score 0):

Think about it without modules. The absolute difference of the $y$-values of the points $Q$ and $R$ is $|ax_Q + b - ax_R - b| = |a(x_Q - x_R)|$. Imagine consecutive lines parallel to the $x$-axis, each with distance $P$ to its nearest neighbours. Your line crosses those parallel exactly as often as $P$ fits into $|a(x_Q - x_R)|$, so $\lfloor \frac{|a(x_Q - x_R)|}{P} \rfloor$ should be the answer.